# Windows command - how to remove flashing cursor (prompt?)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am working with an application that is running inside of a command window. Now inside of that application I added some of my code to run external programs. Basically what it does, is that it calls `cmd.exe /c myprog.bat param1 param2`, and then inside of `myprog.bat` I am calling `start /B c:\myapplication.exe`.

Now the problem is, that after I do this code, the core application (the console window app), starts having the flashing cursor (I believe it's called prompt) in the top left corner of the window. I tried calling `echo off` and `echo on` before and after my code, but that didn't help.

Does anyone have any idea on how could I remove this flashing prompt?

Answer (score 5):

You can not do that with pure Batch commands; a third party program is required.

You may use my CursorSize.exe auxiliary program to do that. This is its help screen:

```
Get or set cursor size.

CursorSize [size|/L]

The cursor size is a percentage (1..100) of the character cell that is filled by the cursor.
Use 0 to hide the cursor; use /L to recover the last hidden cursor.
```

To get CursorSize.exe file, look for program 10-CursorSize.exe.hex at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428&p=17750#p17750); you should also read the instructions at beginning of that topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have windows 10, an ANSI escape sequence should work fine.

You can get the escape character with this:

```
for /F "delims=#" %a in ('prompt #$E# ^& for %a in ^(1^) do rem') do set esc=%a
```

Thus:

```
echo.%esc%[?25l
```

Would hide the cursor.

The letter "l" is the letter "L", but not capitalized.

Comment: To show the cursor again: `echo.%esc%[?25h`… Here `h` = (U+0068,  *Latin Small Letter H*).

Comment: A shorter code to get escape character (\033) to `ESC` variable:
`for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"`

Answer (score 0):

What Aacini said, or these options:

[Noblink](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/noblink.html), TSR which allow no blinking cursors.
[Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), a better cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

---

> - Udate, hidden cursor do not working in Windows 10 (1803), color print ok

---

```bat
::---------------------------------------------------------------------::
:: try this see the picture, (plus multicolor line echo)               :: 
:: the lines with base64 endode echo, generate bg.exe to do the job    :: 
:: bg can do: remove cursor blink, print multi color line & more       ::
::---------------------------------------------------------------------::
```

```bat
@echo off 
%__APPDIR__%Certutil.exe -decode -f "%~f0" "%temp%\bg.exe" >nul 2>&1 && (  
"%temp%\bg.exe" cursor 0 && "%temp%\bg.exe" print \n 
"%temp%\bg.exe" print 6 " Where" f " is" b " the" a " cursor" c " now" e " ?"
"%temp%\bg.exe" print \n )|| color c && echo/E R R O R: "%temp%\bg.exe" not found...

del /q /f "%temp%\bg.b64" >nul 2>&1 & endlocal & goto :EOF || exit/ 

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5v
dCBiZSBydW4gaW4gRE9TIG1vZGUuDQ0KJAAAAAAAAABQRQAATAECAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOAADwMLAQYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1x0AAAAQAAAAIAAAAABAAAAQAAAAAgAA
BAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAgAA5xUBAAMAAAAAABAAABAAAAAAEAAAEAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAgAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADUIAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC50ZXh0AAAA
KA8AAAAQAAAAEAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAGAuZGF0YQAAAJAEAAAAIAAAAAQAAAASAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABVieWB7AAAAACQuAMAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+FGwAAAIsFhCRAAIPACIsIiQ3EI0AA6OoJAADp4wAAALgEAAAAiw2A
JEAAOcgPj9AAAAC4AgAAAIkFACRAAIsFgCRAAEiJBQQkQAC46CNAAFCLBeAjQABQ6NsNAACLBQAkQACLDQQkQAA5yA+NfgAAAIsFACRAAInBQIkFACRAAMHhAosFhCRA
AAHIuRAAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6KENAACDxAyB4P//AABmiQXAI0AAiwUAJEAAicFAiQUAJEAAweECiwWEJEAAAciLCIkNxCNAAA+3BcAjQABQiwXgI0AAUOhjDQAA6BsJ
AADpbv///w+3BfAjQABQiwXgI0AAUOhFDQAAycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAQAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+PSAEAALgEAAAAiQUIJEAAiwWAJEAASIkFDCRAALjoI0AAUIsF4CNAAFDo
7AwAALh/HEAAiQUAIEAAiwWEJEAAg8AMuQoAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6MwMAACDxAzB4BDB+BBmiQXWI0AAiwWEJEAAg8AIuQoAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6J8MAACDxAzB4BDB
+BBmiQXYI0AAD78F1iNAAGaJBcgjQAC4AQAAAGaJBc4jQAC4AQAAAGaJBdAjQAC4AAAAAGaJBdIjQAC4AAAAAGaJBdQjQACLBQgkQACLDQwkQAA5yA+NZwAAAIsFCCRA
AInBQIkFCCRAAMHhAosFhCRAAAHIuRAAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6A8MAACDxAyB4P//AABmiQXMI0AAiwUIJEAAicFAiQUIJEAAweECiwWEJEAAAciLCIkNxCNAAOidBwAA
64XJw1WJ5YHsAAAAAJC4BAAAAIsNgCRAADnID4WDAAAAiwWEJEAAg8AMuQoAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6JoLAACDxAzB4BDB+BBmiQUQJEAAiwWEJEAAg8AIuQoAAABRuQAA
AABRiwhR6G0LAACDxAzB4BDB+BBmiQUSJEAAgewEAAAAieC5BAAAAFG5ECRAAFFQ6FMLAACDxAyLBeAjQABQ6EwLAADJw1WJ5YHsAAAAAJDoQwsAAIXAD4QFAAAA6AIA
AADJw1WJ5YHsAAAAAJDoLQsAAIkFbCBAAIsFbCBAAIXAD4QYAAAAuOAAAACLDWwgQAA5yA+EBQAAAOkRAAAA6PwKAACBwP8AAACJBWwgQADJw1WJ5YHsAAAAAJC49v//
/1Do4QoAAIkF5CNAALgUJEAAUIsF5CNAAFDo0QoAAIsFFCRAAIPIEIPgv4Pg/okFGCRAAIsFGCRAAFCLBeQjQABQ6LEKAAC4HCRAAFC4AQAAAFC4ICRAAFCLBeQjQABQ
6JsKAAC4AgAAAA+3DSAkQAA5yA+FQgAAAIsFKCRAAIkFNCRAALgBAAAAiw00JEAAOcgPhSMAAAAPvwUkJEAAUA+/BSYkQABQuAQgQABQ6FUKAACDxAzpAgAAAOuKiwUU
JEAAUIsF5CNAAFDoKAoAAMnDVYnlgewAAAAAkLg4JEAAUOgpCgAAD7cFRiRAAFAPtwVEJEAAUA+3BUIkQABQD7cFQCRAAFAPtwU8JEAAUA+3BT4kQABQD7cFOiRAAFAP
twU4JEAAULgKIEAAUOjWCQAAg8QkycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAMAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+FJgAAAIsFhCRAAIPACLkKAAAAUbkAAAAAUYsIUehHCQAAg8QMUOieCQAAycNVieWB
7AAAAACQuAMAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+F1wAAALhIJEAAUIsF4CNAAFDodQkAAIsFhCRAAIPACLkKAAAAUbkAAAAAUYsIUejwCAAAg8QMiQVQJEAAiwVQJEAA6QUAAADpCQAA
AIP4AA+FFQAAALgAAAAAiQVMJEAA6WQAAADpCQAAAIP4AQ+FFQAAALgBAAAAiQVMJEAA6UYAAADpCQAAAIP4GQ+FBQAAAOkJAAAAg/gyD4UFAAAA6QkAAACD+GQPhRwA
AAC4AQAAAIkFTCRAAIsFUCRAAIkFSCRAAOkAAAAAuEgkQABQiwXgI0AAUOi4CAAAycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAMAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+FMwAAAIsFhCRAAIPACLkKAAAAUbkA
AAAAUYsIUegMCAAAg8QMgeD/AAAAUIsF4CNAAFDobggAAMnDVYnlgewAAAAAkLgDAAAAiw2AJEAAOcgPj6YAAAC4AQAAAIkFVCRAALgSAAIAiQVYJEAAuAQAAACLDYAk
QAA5yA+PQAAAAIsFhCRAAIPADLkKAAAAUbkAAAAAUYsIUeiRBwAAg8QMiQVUJEAAiwVUJEAAg/gAD40LAAAAuAAAAACJBVQkQACLBVQkQACFwA+ELwAAAIsFhCRAAIPA
CIsNWCRAAFG5AAAAAFGLCFHowgcAAIsFVCRAAIPA/4kFVCRAAOvDycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAEAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+N1QIAAIsFhCRAAIPABIsIiQ1gJEAAiwVgJEAAiQVk
JEAAiwVkJEAAD74IhckPhB0AAACLBWQkQAAPvgiD4V+ICIsFZCRAAECJBWQkQADr0rgiIEAAUIsFYCRAAFDoPQcAAIPECIXAD4QFAAAA6RAAAAC4ABBAAIkFXCRAAOkx
AgAAuCggQABQiwVgJEAAUOgLBwAAg8QIhcAPhAUAAADpEAAAALgdEUAAiQVcJEAA6f8BAAC4LyBAAFCLBWAkQABQ6NkGAACDxAiFwA+EBQAAAOkQAAAAuIQSQACJBVwk
QADpzQEAALg2IEAAUIsFYCRAAFDopwYAAIPECIXAD4QFAAAA6RAAAAC4JhNAAIkFXCRAAOmbAQAAuDsgQABQiwVgJEAAUOh1BgAAg8QIhcAPhAUAAADpEAAAALhEE0AA
iQVcJEAA6WkBAAC4PyBAAFCLBWAkQABQ6EMGAACDxAiFwA+EBQAAAOkQAAAAuJITQACJBVwkQADpNwEAALhFIEAAUIsFYCRAAFDoEQYAAIPECIXAD4QFAAAA6RAAAAC4
chRAAIkFXCRAAOkFAQAAuEogQABQiwVgJEAAUOjfBQAAg8QIhcAPhAUAAADpEAAAALjXFEAAiQVcJEAA6dMAAAC4UCBAAFCLBWAkQABQ6K0FAACDxAiFwA+EBQAAAOkQ
AAAAuBwVQACJBVwkQADpoQAAALhXIEAAUIsFYCRAAFDoewUAAIPECIXAD4QFAAAA6RAAAAC4EhZAAIkFXCRAAOlvAAAAuFwgQABQiwVgJEAAUOhJBQAAg8QIhcAPhAUA
AADpEAAAALhkFkAAiQVcJEAA6T0AAAC4YSBAAFCLBWAkQABQ6BcFAACDxAiFwA+EBQAAAOkQAAAAuJsdQACJBVwkQADpCwAAALgAAAAAiQVcJEAAiwVcJEAAhcAPhBkA
AAC49f///1DoewQAAIkF4CNAAIsFXCRAAP/QycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAAAAACJBWgkQAC4AAAAAIkFbCRAALgAAAAAiQVwJEAAiwXEI0AAiQV4JEAAiwV4JEAAD74IiQ10
JEAAhckPhPIBAACLBXAkQACFwA+EBQAAAOk/AAAAuFwAAACLDXQkQAA5yLgAAAAAD5TAiQVwJEAAhcAPhAUAAADpEgAAAIsFdCRAAFCLBQAgQAD/0IPEBOmOAQAAiwV0
JEAAUOgfBAAAg8QEhcAPhLYAAACLBWwkQACD+AIPjWcAAACLBWwkQABAiQVsJEAAiwVoJEAAweAEiQVoJEAAiwV0JEAAg/g5uAAAAAAPnsCFwA+EDgAAAIsFdCRAAIPo
MOkRAAAAiwV0JEAAg8ggg+hX6QAAAACLDWgkQAABwYkNaCRAAOk7AAAAiwVoJEAAUIsFACBAAP/Qg8QEiwV0JEAAUIsFACBAAP/Qg8QEuAAAAACJBWgkQACJBWwkQACJ
BXAkQADpwQAAAIsFbCRAAIXAD4RiAAAAiwVoJEAAUIsFACBAAP/Qg8QEuFwAAACLDXQkQAA5yLgAAAAAD5TAiQVwJEAAhcAPhAUAAADpEgAAAIsFdCRAAFCLBQAgQAD/
0IPEBLgAAAAAiQVoJEAAiQVsJEAA6VEAAACLBXQkQADpBQAAAOkJAAAAg/huD4UWAAAAuAoAAABQiwUAIEAA/9CDxATpFwAAAIsFdCRAAFCLBQAgQAD/0IPEBOkAAAAA
uAAAAACJBXAkQACLBXgkQABAiQV4JEAA6ff9//+LBWwkQACFwA+EEgAAAIsFaCRAAFCLBQAgQAD/0IPEBMnDVYnlgewAAAAAkItFCOkFAAAA6QkAAACD+AAPhRkAAAAP
vwXWI0AAQGaJBdYjQADp3gAAAOkJAAAAg/gKD4UiAAAAD78F2CNAAEBmiQXYI0AAD78FyCNAAGaJBdYjQADprgAAAA+/BdYjQACD+AAPjIoAAAAPvwXYI0AAg/gAD4x6
AAAAD75FCIgFyiNAAA+/BdYjQABAZokF2iNAAA+/BdgjQABAZokF3CNAALjWI0AAUIHsBAAAAInguQQAAABRudIjQABRUOgdAQAAg8QMgewEAAAAieC5BAAAAFG5ziNA
AFFQ6AABAACDxAy4yiNAAFCLBeAjQABQ6HMBAAAPvwXWI0AAQGaJBdYjQADpAAAAAItFCOkAAAAAycNVieWB7AAAAACQ6E4BAACJBXwkQAC4AAAAAIsNfCRAADnID4QS
AAAAuAMAAABQiwV8JEAAUOgrAQAAycNVieWB7AQAAACQuAAAAACJRfyNRfxQuAAAAABQuIgkQABQuIQkQABQuIAkQABQ6P4AAACDxBTo/gAAAIkFjCRAALjkBAAAUOj1
AAAA6AH5//+LBYwkQABQ6OQAAACLBWwgQABQ6OAAAACDxATJwwAAAP8l1CBAAAAA/yUAIUAAAAD/JdggQAAAAP8lBCFAAAAA/yXcIEAAAAD/JQghQAAAAP8l4CBAAAAA
/yXkIEAAAAD/JQwhQAAAAP8lECFAAAAA/yUUIUAAAAD/JRghQAAAAP8l6CBAAAAA/yUcIUAAAAD/JSAhQAAAAP8lJCFAAAAA/yUoIUAAAAD/JSwhQAAAAP8lRCFAAAAA
/yXsIEAAAAD/JfAgQAAAAP8lMCFAAAAA/yU0IUAAAAD/JUwhQAAAAP8l9CBAAAAA/yU4IUAAAAD/JTwhQAAAAP8l+CBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
SB5AACVkICVkACVkICVkICVkICVkICVkICVkICVkICVkAFBSSU5UAFNQUklURQBMT0NBVEUAX0tCRABLQkQATU9VU0UAVElNRQBTTEVFUABDVVJTT1IARk9OVABQTEFZ
AE1BWElNSVpFAAAAAAAAAFQhAAAAAAAAAAAAANQhAADUIAAAgCEAAAAAAAAAAAAAQiIAAAAhAADEIQAAAAAAAAAAAACPIwAARCEAAMwhAAAAAAAAAAAAAKYjAABMIQAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADfIQAA6SEAAPMhAAD8IQAABSIAAA4iAAAXIgAAICIAACsiAAA7IgAAAAAAAE8iAABsIgAAhiIAAKEiAACwIgAAwSIAANIiAADmIgAA
9SIAAP0iAAAUIwAAKyMAADwjAABSIwAAZSMAAHojAAAAAAAAmSMAAAAAAACxIwAAAAAAAN8hAADpIQAA8yEAAPwhAAAFIgAADiIAABciAAAgIgAAKyIAADsiAAAAAAAA
TyIAAGwiAACGIgAAoSIAALAiAADBIgAA0iIAAOYiAAD1IgAA/SIAABQjAAArIwAAPCMAAFIjAABlIwAAeiMAAAAAAACZIwAAAAAAALEjAAAAAAAAbXN2Y3J0LmRsbAAA
AHB1dGNoYXIAAABzdHJ0b3VsAAAAbWVtY3B5AAAAX2tiaGl0AAAAX2dldGNoAAAAcHJpbnRmAAAAc3RyY21wAAAAaXN4ZGlnaXQAAABfX2dldG1haW5hcmdzAAAAZXhp
dABrZXJuZWwzMi5kbGwAAABHZXRDb25zb2xlU2NyZWVuQnVmZmVySW5mbwAAAFNldENvbnNvbGVUZXh0QXR0cmlidXRlAAAAU2V0Q29uc29sZUN1cnNvclBvc2l0aW9u
AAAAR2V0U3RkSGFuZGxlAAAAR2V0Q29uc29sZU1vZGUAAABTZXRDb25zb2xlTW9kZQAAAFJlYWRDb25zb2xlSW5wdXRBAAAAR2V0TG9jYWxUaW1lAAAAU2xlZXAAAABH
ZXRDb25zb2xlQ3Vyc29ySW5mbwAAAFNldENvbnNvbGVDdXJzb3JJbmZvAAAAU2V0Q29uc29sZUZvbnQAAABXcml0ZUNvbnNvbGVPdXRwdXRBAAAAR2V0Q29uc29sZVdp
bmRvdwAAAEdldENvbnNvbGVPdXRwdXRDUAAAAFNldENvbnNvbGVPdXRwdXRDUAB3aW5tbS5kbGwAAABQbGF5U291bmRBAHVzZXIzMi5kbGwAAABTaG93V2luZG93AAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The idea came from this [link](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1075)